# A problem about real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\mathbf{Question}$: Can we construct an outer measure that is determined by the non-measurable set of Vitali?
Although I can construct an non-measurable set, I cannot calculate its outer measure. Now I want to construct two disjoint sets: A and B which satisfy the following :
$$ m^*(A \cup B) <m^*(A) +m^*(B)$$
$m^*(\cdot)$ stands for outer measure

Comment: You mean outer-measure?

Comment: yes@user10354138

Comment: What does it _mean_ to say an outer measure is "determined by" a set???